# How can i fix language for the grammar does not match the language of the speech recognizer error in vb

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, speech-recognition

Hello in visual basic I am attempting to create a speech recognition system that can help me out with my life on the computer. I called my assistant Jarvis. For this project I imported system.speech.dll. And now im receiving this error:

**An error occurred creating the form. See Exception.InnerException for details.  The error is: The language for the grammar does not match the language of the speech recognizer.**

Here is my code

```
Imports System.Speech.Recognition
Imports System.Speech.Recognition.SrgsGrammar
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices 'For Monitor Command

Public Class Form1
    'This object represents the Speech recognition engine
    Private recognizer As SpeechRecognizer
    Dim QuestionEvent As String

    Public Sub New()

        InitializeComponent() ' This call is required by the Windows Form Designer.

        recognizer = New SpeechRecognizer() ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.

        AddHandler recognizer.SpeechDetected, AddressOf recognizer_SpeechDetected 'this event is raised when the user begins to speak

        AddHandler recognizer.SpeechRecognitionRejected, AddressOf recognizer_SpeechRecognitionRejected 'this is raised when spoken words are not recognized as compliant to our grammar rules

        AddHandler recognizer.SpeechRecognized, AddressOf recognizer_SpeechRecognized 'this is raised when the application correctly recognizes spoken words


        'The rule is that each choice in the first Append method can be combined with each word specified
        'in the second method.
        Dim grammar As New GrammarBuilder()
        grammar.Append(New Choices(System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("Commands.txt")))

        'A grammar must be loaded into the engine. This is possible by loading an object or an xml file
        recognizer.LoadGrammar(New Grammar(grammar))


    End Sub

    Private Sub recognizer_SpeechRecognized(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As SpeechRecognizedEventArgs)
        Dim Jarvis = CreateObject("sapi.spvoice")
        Select e.Result.Text.ToUpper

            'GREETINGS
            Case Is = "HELLO JARVIS"
                Jarvis.Speak("Hello sir")
            Case Is = "GOODBYE JARVIS"
                Jarvis.Speak("Until next time")
                Me.Close()

                'DATE / TIME / WEATHER
            Case Is = "WHAT TIME IS IT"
                Jarvis.Speak(Format(Now, "Short Time"))
            Case Is = "HOWS THE WEATHER"
                System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&ie=UTF-8#output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=weather&oq=&gs_l=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.47008514,d.eWU&fp=6c7f8a5fed4db490&biw=1366&bih=643&ion=1&pf=p&pdl=300")
                Jarvis.Speak("Searching for local weather")


                'WEBSITES
            Case Is = "RUN FACEBOOK"
                System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("http://www.facebook.com")
            Case Is = "RUN GOOGLE"
                System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("http://www.google.com")
            Case Is = "RUN YAHOO"
                System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("http://www.yahoo.com")
            Case Is = "RUN PANDORA"
                System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("http://www.pandora.com")
            Case Is = "RUN THE PIRATE BAY"
                System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("http://www.thepiratebay.se")
            Case Is = "RUN YOUTUBE"
                System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("http://www.youtube.com")

                'MISCELLANEOUS
            Case Is = "SHOW COMMANDS"
                lbCommands.Visible = True
                Jarvis.speak("Here we are")
            Case Is = "HIDE COMMANDS"
                lbCommands.Visible = False
                Jarvis.speak("Very well")
            Case Is = "OPEN DISK DRIVE"
                Dim oWMP = CreateObject("WMPlayer.OCX.7")
                Dim CDROM = oWMP.cdromCollection
                If CDROM.Count = 2 Then
                    CDROM.Item(1).Eject()
                    Jarvis.speak("Its now open")
                End If
            Case Is = "MONITOR OFF"
                SendMessage(Me.Handle.ToInt32(), WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_MONITORPOWER, 2)
                Jarvis.Speak("I'll just close my eyes for a minute")
        End Select
    End Sub
    'LABEL DETECT / REJECT
    Private Sub recognizer_SpeechDetected(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As SpeechDetectedEventArgs)

        Label1.ForeColor = Color.Green : Label1.BackColor = Color.Transparent : Label1.Text = "Speech engine has detected that you spoke something"
    End Sub
    Private Sub recognizer_SpeechRecognitionRejected(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As SpeechRecognitionRejectedEventArgs)

        Label1.ForeColor = Color.Red : Label1.BackColor = Color.Transparent : Label1.Text = ("Sorry but the " & e.Result.Text & " phrase could not be recognized")

    End Sub

    'LOADS THE COMMANDS INTO AN ARRAY AND LISTBOX
    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim Commands() As String = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("Commands.txt")
        For i As Integer = 0 To Commands.Count - 1
            lbCommands.Items.Add(Commands(i))
        Next
    End Sub

    'HIDES COMMANDS LIST BOX
    Private Sub lbCommands_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles lbCommands.SelectedIndexChanged
        lbCommands.Visible = False
    End Sub

    'FOR MONITOR COMMAND
    Public WM_SYSCOMMAND As Integer = &H112
    Public SC_MONITORPOWER As Integer = &HF170
    <DllImport("user32.dll")> _
    Private Shared Function SendMessage(ByVal hWnd As Integer, ByVal hMsg As Integer, ByVal wParam As Integer, ByVal lParam As Integer) As Integer
    End Function

End Class
```

I am receiving that error due to this line of code `recognizer.LoadGrammar(New Grammar(grammar))` Howver I am not sure how to fix the line

[Here is an image of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VRS6I.png)

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**I have worked this out.**

You can fix this by using this code before declaring the recogniser

**First import this**

```
Imports System.Threading
Imports System.Globalization
```

**Secondly add this**

```
   Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = New CultureInfo("en-GB")
```

**'or your current language and country'**

```
   Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = New CultureInfo("en-GB")
```

**'or your current language and country'**

Answer (score 0):

Like I sead in diferent forum thed. I hade the same problem on my friends komputer. So I made this (it is just part of the code, because all the code is realy long):

```
...
RecognizerInfo recognizerInfo = null;

foreach (RecognizerInfo ri in SpeechRecognitionEngine.InstalledRecognizers())
{
   if ((ri.Culture.TwoLetterISOLanguageName.Equals("en")) && (recognizerInfo == null))
   {
      recognizerInfo = ri;
      break;
   }

}

SpeechRecognitionEngine SpeachRecognition = new SpeechRecognitionEngine(recognizerInfo);

GrammarBuilder gb = new GrammarBuilder(startLiserninFraze);
gb.Culture = recognizerInfo.Culture;
grammar = new Grammar(gb);
SpeachRecognition.RequestRecognizerUpdate();
SpeachRecognition.LoadGrammar(grammar);
SpeachRecognition.SpeechRecognized += SpeachRecognition_SpeechRecognized;
SpeachRecognition.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();
SpeachRecognition.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple);
...
```

So this should work. My friends PC supported 2 instances of "en" or in "eng". Not shure why. So the code selects first one. I found some peaces of code in te internet and some of this is made by me.

```
 SpeachRecognition.SpeechRecognized += SpeachRecognition_SpeechRecognized;
```

is made to make an event when everything is recognized. just type:

SpeachRecognition.SpeechRecognized +=

and the press TAB button few times. and then in the botom of code it will generate something like that:

```
void SpeachRecognition_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
   {
       //then will be some line that you need to replace with your code
   }
```

I hope this will help. :)

**Your option is shorter. But after entering it I got e diferent error about sintesyzer not instaled or language unavailable when running ower VS 2013. after deleting the code release version had the same error ir I runn from VS, but from explorer it is ok. Dose anyone know why is that?**

Answer (score 0):

Be careful: By the construction of the object of type **SpeechRecognitionEngine** including the parameter of **CultureInfo** and also the culture property of the **Grammar** object should be the same. 
For example - I earned the same described exception using "en-US" for both objects. 
But as I used "en-GB" for both object in my german environment, the program works as expected!
So it could be useful to detect the allowed cultures, first.
In my point of view, you can avoid the manipulation of >> Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture << and you should focus the right settings of the **SpeechRecognitionEngine** and the **Grammar** objects with allowed/installed cultures.